# what we should do when the alert comes in connection did fail with error?

Tags: iphone

Im trying to connect to server, if server is down the alert comes server down in connection did fail with error. on the tap of ok button what is the best approach to  do afterwords.

Comment: you can request again on ok button .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegate methods of the UIAlertview controller.

## import

```
@interface ARReachabilityAlertView : UIAlertView <UIAlertViewDelegate> {
}

@end
```

Set up the UIAlertView subclass implementation:

```
#import "ARReachabilityAlertView.h"

@implementation ARReachabilityAlertView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    [self setTitle:@"Error"];
    [self setMessage:@"This application won't run without a network connection. Do you want to quit?"];
    [self addButtonWithTitle:@"Quit"];
    [self addButtonWithTitle:@"Continue"];
    [self setDelegate:self];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
  if (buttonIndex == 0)
    exit(0); // quit application if "Quit" is pressed; otherwise, do nothing
}

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  [super drawRect:rect];
}

- (void) dealloc {
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

More details for this question refer the same [answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814300/using-uialertview-in-a-manner-similar-to-windows-messagebox)